# Mouse.WheelScrollLines Property in C#

Tags: c#, mouse, mousewheel

So I made a custom Scroll Bar in C# but I would like to add Windows Properties to it. the problem is, I cant seem to get the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices` namespace to work in C#. any ideas on how to fix this.

Simply put the IDE does not identify it as a namespace. it does however identify `MicroSoft.VisualBasic`. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.mouse.wheelscrolllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what I want to do but in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a reference `MicroSoft.VisualBasic` : 
Project > Add Reference ... in the .NET tab select `Microsoft.VisualBasic`.